# How to overwrite StorageFile (image) that is being shown in the UI [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10

I have a listview, with an OberservableCollection binding to its itemsource. Each listviewitem shows an image (the imagesource is set by an URI locating a file in the localfolder:

```
<Image Source={x:Bind ImageURI} />
```

Now I want the user to be able to change the file, but when I overwrite it I get a System.UnauthorizedException which makes sense, since the image is 'in use' (it's shown on the screen).

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Now I have tried to replace the image quickly with a different image, and THEN overwrite the file, but the same problem still occurs.

```
public static async Task SaveToLocalStorage(string FileName, WriteableBitmap Bitmap)
    {       
        StorageFile outputFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            byte[] pixels;
            using (Stream stream = Bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                pixels = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
                await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
            }
            // Encode pixels into stream
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, writeStream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, (uint)Bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)Bitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, pixels);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Regards,
Niels

Comment: How did you replace the image? I think your guess is right. The problem here is that the image shown in the UI still holds the reference to the file your are trying to modify.

Comment: I just updates the ObservableCollection[Item] with a new Uri to link to. You see that the ListView gets updated, but it still seems to be 'in use' somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding the image path and want to change what is displayed, rather than replace the file on disk, add the new image with a different filename and then update the viewmodel so the new image is displayed instead.

Comment: I want to do both actually..

Would the best solution be:

1) Make a new file with (2) after it, bind this to the UI.
2) Next time the page loads, remove the original file and rename the (2) to the original one?

Comment: @Niels Yes, make the new file and update the viewmodel. Next time the app or page loads (where you're no longer using the old file) remove the file that's no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for your issue might be using a [Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to convert `ImageURI` to a [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) for binding. And in the Converter, we can use [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to release the file resource.

Following is a sample using the code you've posted:

**XAML:**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ImageURIConverter x:Key="ImageURIConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ImageList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ViewModel">
                <Image Height="200" Source="{x:Bind ImageURI, Converter={StaticResource ImageURIConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ImageList = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel> { new ViewModel { ImageURI = "ms-appdata:///local/1.png" }, new ViewModel { ImageURI = "ms-appdata:///local/2.png" }, new ViewModel { ImageURI = "ms-appdata:///local/3.png" } };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> ImageList;

    private async void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            WriteableBitmap Bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                Bitmap.SetSource(stream);
            }

            var clickedItem = e.ClickedItem as ViewModel;

            var FileName = clickedItem.ImageURI.Replace("ms-appdata:///local/", string.Empty);

            await SaveToLocalStorage(FileName, Bitmap);

            clickedItem.NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageURI");
        }
    }

    public static async Task SaveToLocalStorage(string FileName, WriteableBitmap Bitmap)
    {
        StorageFile outputFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            byte[] pixels;
            using (Stream stream = Bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                pixels = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
                await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
            }
            // Encode pixels into stream
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, writeStream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, (uint)Bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)Bitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96, pixels);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}

public class ImageURIConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();

        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = (StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(value.ToString())).AsTask().Result).OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read).AsTask().Result)
            image.SetSource(stream);

        return image;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string imageURI;

    public string ImageURI
    {
        get
        {
            return imageURI;
        }

        set
        {
            imageURI = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

However, please note that using [`Task.Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) might not be a good practice is some scenarios as it may block your UI. But I think it's a simple solution for your problem, you can decide whether to use it according to your real scenario.